# How to get json string from array inside json array

Tags: android, json

#### Initial JSON

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "request": [
        [
          {
            "name": "John""email": "John@gmail.com"
          }
        ],
        [
          "name": "William""email": "William@gmail.com"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Corrected JSON as it was not passing through JSONLint

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "request": [
        {
          "name": "John",
          "email": "John@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "William",
          "email": "William@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to extract an array of JSON inside JSON array.I got error message as

> json array cannot be converted into JSON Object.

Comment: would you show your code?

Comment: side note: your json string is invalid : ["name": "William""email": "William@gmail.com"] is not a valid array and you don't have commas between name/val pairs. Also, I suspect you want "request" to contain an array of objects, not more arrays?

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas shouldn't the json string be left as-is in the original post and let it's inaccuracy be explained along with a solution in an answer? Eg. in Anjali's answer below, other than that he didn't catch the missing commas between the key/val pairs, his answer was correct, but after the edit to the OP it now doesn't make any sense. I'm not sure we should be fixing coding errors etc when editing the original question.

Comment: @mjp66 That's questionable and probably belongs to Meta(if that wasn't asked already). Meanwhile, I could revert my edit. That's not a ice-breaker.

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas Yeah, it was asked already: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code . I know I'm also sometimes tempted to fix the obvious directly in the original question but doing so can mess up everyone's answers ;)

Comment: @mjp66 Apparently this time I didn't affect answers, so let's leave it as it is. I'll be more careful next time. Thanks!

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas Anjali's parsing is now wrong because of it: JSONArray mRequestChildJson = jsonRequest.getJSONArray(0); - there's no JSONArray here now. I realize there's still the matter of the commas between the key/vals which Anjali should address in his answer but otherwise his solution went from correct to wrong.

Comment: @mjp66 Added both of them to question and seperated these. :)

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas Cool! Good compromise! :)

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help to parse your Json:

```
try {

            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
            JSONArray dataJsonArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("data");
            JSONArray jsonRequest = dataJsonArray.getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("request");
            JSONArray mRequestChildJson = jsonRequest.getJSONArray(0);
            JSONObject innerJson = mRequestChildJson.getJSONObject(0);
            LogHandler.e("TAG",
                    "mRequestChildJson" + innerJson.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

don't forgot to add check of has Key and size of array.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

may be you're on right track but casting it in object

```
JSONArray JArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
                String str = result.toString();

                System.out.println("prov-request -->"+str);

                JSONObject json=new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonnew=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray jsonarrayROW = jsonnew.getJSONArray("request");
for(int j=0;j<jsonarrayROW.length();j++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);

                            date.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            from.add(jsonObject.getString("email"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```